# Use A Union Or A Join - What Is Faster

Tags: sql, mysql

I just wonder if you had a table and you unioned it would it be more efficent then using a join??

I do know that the join creates more columns but this is more theoretical - Will the union need to do a nested loop scan of the other table like a join would have to?

Comment: Until this question and/or answers has some concrete examples, I am voting to close as too misleading.

Comment: If Union/Union All simply concatenates the groups, are they no longer in sorted order? As such, would operations farther down the line (like if the union is in a subquery or CTE) suffer performance issues? Join should result in a sorted or at least hash-mapped output.

Comment: "Unioned it" & "using a join" mean nothing. Join & union are different operators. They return different things. What thing *expressible via one of those plus other operators* are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Union will be faster, as it simply passes the first SELECT statement, and then parses the second SELECT statement and adds the results to the end of the output table.

The Join will go through each row of both tables, finding matches in the other table therefore needing a lot more processing due to searching for matching rows for each and every row.

#### EDIT

By Union, I mean Union All as it seemed adequate for what you were trying to achieve. Although a normal Union is generally faster then Join.

#### EDIT 2 (Reply to @seebiscuit 's comment)

I don't agree with him. Technically speaking no matter how good your join is, a "JOIN" is still more expensive than a pure concatenation. I made a blog post to prove it at my blog [codePERF[dot]net](http://www.codeperf.net/sql-union-vs-join-performance/). Practically speaking they serve 2 completely different purposes and it is more important to ensure your indexing is right and using the right tool for the job.

Technically, I think it can be summed using the following 2 execution plans  taken from my blog post:

## `UNION ALL` Execution Plan

[image: UNION ALL Execution Plan]

## `JOIN` Execution Plan

[image: JOIN Execution Plan]

## Practical Results

Practically speaking the difference on a clustered index lookup is negligible:

[image: Benchmark Results]

Comment: What you are describing is no UNION but UNION ALL. A UNION has to match the records between the results to be able to remove the duplicates. That can be even more costly than doing a join.

Comment: Even when removing duplicates all it has to do is one pass on the other table, and rather then adding each row to the output table, it does a simple check whether it already exists. And yes it may under certain circumstance be slower. Therefore poster you should use UNION ALL as from the sounds of it, it should be adequate for you.

Thanks for the note.

Comment: Wondering what you thought of @Domas Mituzas answer, below.

Comment: @seebiscuit see my edit for my comments. No matter what a like for like  `UNION ALL` will be faster then any `JOIN`. But most important thing is, they are 2 different tools for 2 different kinds of jobs.

Comment: MySQL always creates a temp table and adds each `SELECT` (of the `UNION`) to it.  After than, it dedups (if using `UNION DISTINCT`, which is the default), and finally delivers the temp table as the resultset.  No parallelism.  No avoiding the temp table (until very recent versions; and then only in limited circumstances).

Comment: I am downvoting this answer because it makes the blanket, incorrect, statement that `UNION` is faster.  Sure, it is faster in certain queries, but not most, and certainly not all.

Answer (score 29):

`JOIN` and `UNION` have two different purposes. `JOIN` is used to add additional tables to a query for the purpose of adding selection criteria and possibly additional columns. `UNION` is used to combine the results of two distinct queries with the same columns. Asking which is more efficient is like asking which of "a loaf of bread" and "the blowing wind" is more "orange".

Comment: "a loaf of bread" is definitely more "orange" than "the blowing wind" ;-)

Comment: Not necessarily, they can be used to achieve the exact same thing. A join with ON x OR y inside (SLOW) or 2 Queries with seperate join X and Join Y  unioned together. Same result, BIG Difference in performance.

Comment: A succinct description of when to use `JOIN` and when to use `UNION`.  The counter arguments involve kludges to make one achieve the purpose of the other.

Comment: It is not necessarily true. For example when using JPA's inheritance, choosing between JOIN and UNION is done declaratively by the @Inheritance annotation.

Answer (score 11):

sorry to break your party, but a well written join will be faster than a union.

- it uses more lightweight statistics collection model (based on cardinality, rather than random dives)
- query will get *parsed* only once (no need for multiple subselect evaluation)
- resultset will not be materialized in a temptable (it gets even for UNION ALL)

Comment: My union all query is taking longer and I was all confused. Thanks to your explanation , I dont have to break my head.

Comment: `JOIN` and "subselect" are two different things.  Your bullet item #2 does not (usually) apply.

Answer (score 3):

A single SELECT will use no more than one index per table. 
A UNION will use no more than one index per SELECT in the union.

The UNION will make better use of indexes which could result in a faster query.