# MSQL join tables with same columns

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, date-range

I looked around here and i can't find an answer to this. It might be that I don't know the right term to look for.

I have about 15 tables, all with the same columns and similar data. The only differences between them is date created.

I want to search some of them like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_2010, table_2011 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2011-04-01'
ORDER BY date_created
```

But i don't believe that will work because it will treat all my data as 2 tables, and create ambiguous fields :P

Any suggestions? Is this a union job or something?!

Comment: Can you please provide some test data and an expected result? Because I can think of several results of what you are trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from (SELECT * FROM table_2010
      WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2011-04-01'
      union
      SELECT * FROM table_2011
      WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2011-04-01'
) as t
ORDER BY date_created
```

Comment: union is starting to make sense to me. But i dont understand the 'as t' you added.

Comment: You can't sort parts of a union. You need to sort the complete result. That is why all unions are treated as one result and then get sorted. You need to give your combined result a table name. In this case it is `t`.

Answer (score 1):

create table object, try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_2010 AS t1, table_2011 AS t2
WHERE ( t1.date_created BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2011-04-01' AND t2.date_created BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2011-04-01')
ORDER BY t1.date_created,t2.date_created
```

Comment: what is the benefit in creating a table object if i don't have to? newbe Q

Comment: object will simply the query look. we can use simply object instant of large table name.example use **t1.date_created** instant of **table_2010.date_created**. Which one is easy ask yourself.

Comment: @cadi: I go with **Union**. Union is fast than join have a look at this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309936/use-a-union-or-a-join-what-is-faster)

Answer (score 0):

Use alias'

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_2010 as t2010, table_2011 as t2011 
WHERE t2010.date_created BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2011-04-01'
ORDER BY t2010.date_created
```

Comment: im getting table doesn't exist errors here. Its because its looking for the tables 't2010' and 't2011' which i thought would behave as alias'. They are all inside the one database, is this code still correct?

Comment: sorry, need forgot to use `as` in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: ah ha that makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT table_2010.*, table_2011.* 
FROM table_2010, table_2011 
WHERE table_2010.date_created >= '2010-04-01' AND table_2011.date_created <= '2011-04-01'
ORDER BY table_2010.date_created, table_2011.date_created
```

**I believe in 2010 table you have data for 2010 year only and 2011 table have data for 2011 year only.**

Comment: if this solves your problem, please accept the answer. This is how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  FROM table_2010 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2011-04-01' ORDER BY date_created 

union

SELECT *  FROM table_2011 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2011-04-01' ORDER BY date_created
```

Comment: this is the simplest looking result

Answer (score 0):

That's a union, but you'll need to select from the union to get order across tables, though you might be able to skip that step if date_created is always in the year of the table

```
Select * From (
SELECT *  FROM table_2010
WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2011-04-01'
Union all
Select * From Table_2010
WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2011-04-01'
) allmyTables
ORDER BY date_created
```