# Select all columns from two tables

Tags: postgresql, select

Lets say I have the following:

**table_a**

```
| id |    date    | order_id | sku | price |
--------------------------------------------
| 10 | 2016-08-18 |    111   | ABC |   10  |
```

**table_b**

```
| id |    date    | order_id | description | type | notes | valid |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 50 | 2016-08-18 |    111   |     test    |  AA  |       | true  |
```

I want to get get all columns from both tables, so the resulting table looks like this:

```
| id |    date    | order_id | sku | price | description | type | notes | valid |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 10 | 2016-08-18 |    111   | ABC |   10  |             |      |       |       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 50 | 2016-08-18 |    111   |     |       |     test    |  AA  |       | true  |
```

I tried union:

```
(
 SELECT *
 from table_a
 where table_a.date > Date('today')
)
UNION 
(
 SELECT *
 from table_b
 where table_b.date > Date('today')
)
```

But I get a:

```
ERROR: each UNION query must have the same number of columns
```

How can this be fixed / is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, instead of UNION you can just JOIN them:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_a A
JOIN    table_b B USING ( id )
WHERE   A.date > TIMESTAMP 'TODAY'
  AND   B.date > TIMESTAMP 'TODAY';
```

See more options: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN

Comment: If there are millions of rows, which would be better for this type of query with respect to performance? union or join?

Comment: @user4658312 here has been discussion about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309936/use-a-union-or-a-join-what-is-faster. But since you have 2 different table structures to 'merge' into one view then for your case JOIN is more up to that task.

Answer (score 1):

Easily :)

```
(
 SELECT id, date, order_id, sku, price, NULL AS description, NULL AS type, NULL AS notes, NULL AS valid
 from table_a
 where table_a.date > Date('today')
)
UNION 
(
 SELECT id, date, order_id, NULL AS sku, NULL AS price, description, type, notes, valid
 from table_b
 where table_b.date > Date('today')
)
```