# Do Multiple Left Join on condition and get non null column value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a table containing the last comments posted on the website, and I'd like to join a different table depending on the comment type.

Comments Table is similar to this structure:

```
id | type | ressource_id |
---+------+--------------+
1  |  1   |      10      |
2  |  3   |       7      |
3  |  3   |      12      |
4  |  1   |      22      |
5  |  4   |      22      |
6  |  5   |      23      |
```

News Table:

```
news_id | notes|     date     |
--------+------+--------------+
10      |      |  2015-08-12  |
22      |      |  2015-07-12  |
```

Tutorial Table:

```
tuto_id | notes|     date     |
--------+------+--------------+
7       |      |  2015-06-15  |
12      |      |  2015-05-14  |
```

... Similar table for type = 4, 5, 6

Now in order to get specific comments I am doing a left join on the two tables.

```
SELECT co.*
  FROM Comments co
       LEFT JOIN News n 
              ON co.id = n.news_id AND co.type = 1
       LEFT JOIN Tutorial t
              ON co.id = t.tuto_id AND co.type = 3
 WHERE (co.type IN (1,3))
```

I am interested in getting the date from the left table. How can I include that column in output list.

Result desired: (date from joining table)

```
id | type | ressource_id |     date     |
---+------+--------------+--------------+
1  |  1   |      10      |  2015-08-12  |
2  |  3   |       7      |  2015-06-15  |
3  |  3   |      12      |  2015-05-14  |
4  |  1   |      22      |  2015-07-12  |
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will never get a date from `News` and `Tutorial` for the same `comment you might go with`COALESCE`:

```
SELECT co.*, COALESCE(n.date,t.date)
  FROM Comments co
       LEFT JOIN News n 
              ON co.id = n.news_id AND co.type = 1
       LEFT JOIN Tutorial t
              ON co.id = t.tuto_id AND co.type = 3
 WHERE (co.type IN (1,3))
```

`COALESCE` will return the first argument that is not `null`, so if there is a matching news it will return the date from `News` and if there is no matching news but a matching tutorial it will return the date from `Tutorial`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT co.*,coalesce(n.date,t.date)
  FROM Comments co
       LEFT JOIN News n 
              ON co.id = n.news_id AND co.type = 1
       LEFT JOIN Tutorial t
              ON co.id = t.tuto_id AND co.type = 3
 WHERE (co.type IN (1,3))
 and (co.id = n.news_id or co.id = t.tuto_id)
```

Comment: Can you tell me why would we need the and condition in where ?

Comment: @panxpress, condition in where because cuting not not needed recordrs but in condition in left join not cuting

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION operator also.

```
(SELECT co.*,n.date as [date]
  FROM Comments co
       LEFT JOIN News n 
              ON co.id = n.news_id AND co.type = 1)
UNION ALL
    (SELECT co.*,t.date
      FROM Comments co
       LEFT JOIN Tutorial t
              ON co.id = t.tuto_id AND co.type = 3)
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Can you comment on the performance compared to the left join? Thanks!

Comment: I think union.. user can read more about the performance impact over this link [Link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309936/use-a-union-or-a-join-what-is-faster)