# Execution details for UNION vs FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, union

I'm dealing with two SQL tables that contains 120,000,000 records each. Few records (approx 60,000) are duplicated across the two tables. Structure of both tables are the same.

There are 40 columns in each table. I need to union the records into one of the table.

I know of two ways to do it (both give me the desired output). I would like to know which ways is better and is there is a much better way please?

Method 1:

```
SELECT * INTO Table1_copy FROM Table1

DROP TABLE Table1

SELECT * INTO Table1 FROM Table1_copy
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Table2

DROP TABLE Table1_copy
```

Method 2:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 <br>
SELECT Table2.Col1, Table2.Col2 <br>
FROM TAB1 <br>
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2  <br>
ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1 AND Table1.Col2 = Table2.Col2 <br>
WHERE Table1.Col1 IS NULL AND Table1.Col2 IS NULL
```

Use of `UNION` seem to be a better choice, but is anyone able to address the space issue around having to select large datasets into a new table and dropping it. 
120,000,000 records is just one example. There are other tables with larger number of records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use A Union Or A Join - What Is Faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309936/use-a-union-or-a-join-what-is-faster)

Comment: UNION ALL is perhaps faster than UNION.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` when a `LEFT JOIN` does what you need. Also, there is no need to check whether both Col1 and Col2 are NULL. A NULL value does not equal NULL, so if Col1 is NULL, Table1 can not equal Table2. Just use `WHERE Table1.Col1 IS NULL`

Comment: jarlh - UNION ALL retains the duplicates between the tables, which is not what is requested.

Comment: By "duplicated", do you mean _all_ the columns?  Or just some unique key?  Can there be duplicate rows within either of the tables?  Are there sequences?  If so, do they match?  What unique keys exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you use a third table.

I would go with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (<Columns list>)
SELECT <Columns list> FROM Table2
EXCEPT 
SELECT <Columns list> FROM Table1
```

If except isn't fast enough, perhaps use not exists and add the relevant indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would do:

```
SELECT * INTO Table1
FROM Table1_copy;

CREATE INDEX idx_table1_copy_2 ON table1_copy(col1, col2);

INSERT INTO table1 (. . .)
    SELECT *
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM table1_copy t1
                      WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
                     );
```

I should note that the two methods you describe are NOT equivalent.  `UNION` removes duplicates within tables and between tables, so the rows in the new table are all distinct.  `FULL OUTER JOIN` does not remove duplicates from within tables.

Comment: 'FULL OUTER JOIN does not remove duplicates from within tables' - Good point Gordon. I do not have duplicates within each table.