# MySQL - Multiple JOIN on Same Table

Tags: mysql, performance

I have table foo1 which given below

*foo1*

```
 +----+---------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
    | Id | OrderId |    OrderNote    | SentSalesmanId | OrderedSalesmanId | ConfirmedSalesmanId |
    +----+---------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
    |  2 |    1    | important order |        1       |         2         |          3          |
    +----+---------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

and salesman table which contains Id, Code and Name.

*salesman*

```
+----+-------+-------+
| Id | Code  | Name  |
+----+-------+-------+
| 1  | S1001 | N1001 |
+----+-------+-------+
| 2  | S1002 | N1002 |
+----+-------+-------+
| 3  | S1003 | N1003 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

As you can see in table foo1 there are 3 columns(SentSalesmanId, OrderedSalesmanId and ConfirmedSalesmanId) related with salesman table.

Here is my query

```
SELECT
  f.Id,
  f.OrderId,
  f.OrderNote,
  s1.Code AS SentSalesmanCode,
  s2.Code AS OrderedSalesmanCode,
  s3.Code AS ConfirmedSalesmanCode
FROM
    foo1 f
INNER JOIN salesman s1 ON (s1.Id = f.SentSalesmanId)
INNER JOIN salesman s2 ON (s2.Id = f.OrderedSalesmanId)
INNER JOIN salesman s3 ON (s3.Id = f.ConfirmedSalesmanId);
```

Here is my expected output

```
+----+---------+------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| Id | OrderId | OrderNote        | SentSalesmanCode | OrderedSalesmanCode | ConfirmedSalesmanCode |
+----+---------+------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|  2 |    1    | important order! |       S1001      |        S1002        |         S1003         |
+----+---------+------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

This query gives what I want, but it works slow for big data. Do I have to use JOIN three times to salesman table? Can't I write it with one JOIN or Is there any way which is more efficient?

Thanks.

Comment: You never specified what is the desired output.

Comment: Sorry. Question was updated. @tilz0R

Comment: creating indexes of those three columns will help.

Comment: Try to run `EXPLAIN SELECT ....` it will tell you why it is slow. This is correct way of joining. How many records do you have?

Comment: About 3m records in foo1, 15-20 recors in salesman. I will try EXPLAIN SELECT. Thanks for suggestion :) @martin.malek

Comment: @KemalGüler This is nothing.. In this join case there can be problem when the salesman has many records. Try EXPLAIN and than try the query you have but as subquery, the parent query will do only COUNT(*). It's possible that there is not problem in the query but on network. Try to have a look at percona toolkit, there are more profiling tools for this.

Comment: In my case using unions to construct this same query made 10 times fast in ms sql

Comment: @BhavikPatel - Creating indexes on those 3 columns will not help.  (1) multiple indexes are almost never used; (2) the query will work the other direction; that is, it will scan `foo1`, then lookup `salesman`.

Comment: @Khalil - how can `UNION` be used?

Comment: Fetching 3m records takes time.  How long does it take without the joins?

Comment: @RickJames See this link for example [QueryUsingUnions](https://gist.github.com/KhalilMohammad/353a1ae9b845c50fa3406603bc7ea370)

Comment: @RickJames in sql server I had above 10m record. Before unions query took 25 to 26 min. After indexing and converting it into a union query .Now this query exectued in 1.2 min.

Comment: @Khalil - The first 2 SELECTs use `s3` without defining it.  After fixing that, you get 3 rows instead of one for each item.  That could be fixed by putting the `UNIONs` as a subquery in another `SELECT` that merges the `NULL`.  This takes even more overhead.  OTOH, if s1,s2,s3 are "small", then the `UNION` might run "fast". by starting with s1,s2,s3 _instead of foo_.  You should provide such as an Answer?

Comment: @Khalil - another requirement for UNION to be fast: it must not hit many of the rows of `foo`.

Comment: @RickJames Also that was a typo. Check gist again.check execution plan for both queries. Also check execution plan for sub queries. I think sometimes for complex queries using unions makes better execution plans.

Comment: @RickJames  here is some reference on this [union vs joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309936/use-a-union-or-a-join-what-is-faster)

Comment: Each `SELECT` in a `UNION` is free to use a different index.  This is part of what your scheme is depending on.  In particular, you are depending on `f` to have `INDEX(SentSalesmanId)` and two other one-col indexes.

Comment: @Khalil - I bled all over that "union vs joins" Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your query.  This should be fast.  If it is going slow, you probably need to make sure your tables are indexed correctly.

```
SHOW INDEX FROM foo1
SHOW INDEX FROM salesman
```

would be helpful if you could add them to your question.  We would then have # rows and cardinality for the fields involved.

Comment: Thanks for answer :)

Comment: I still don't see the indexes on your tables.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the query?  A query with NO WHERE, ORDER BY.  Please show us the entire query.  Each SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name  and  each SHOW INDEX FROM table_name when you have time and someone will have an idea or two for you.