# Joining a column of table to multiple columns of other table in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a  table `table1`  with  columns `A`,`B`(`A` and `B` forms the primary key ),`C`,`D`,`E` and  `table2`  with  column  `F`

I need to pull the  distinct  values of the `A` and  `B`  where `C` or `D` or `E` is  valid.
Requirement to be met is  table1.C=table2.F or table1.D=table2.F or table1.E=table2.F

SQL I am using is below :

```
sel  A,B from table1
inner  join table2
on table1.C=table2.F
**union**
sel  A,B from table1
inner  join table2
on table1.D=table2.F
**union**
sel  A,B from table1
inner  join table2
on table1.E=table2.F
```

Is there a better approach so that all this can be fitted in a single join ?

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server and MySQL and teradata here, which are you using.

Comment: Please include sample data and expected outcome so we have a better image of your problem. Also is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I've removed the different dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used!

Comment: Of course the `OR` will result in a *product join*. How big are those tables?  Btw, `or`ed joins are usually sign of a bad data model.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A,B FROM
table1 
INNER JOIN
table2 ON table1.C=table2.F 
       OR table1.D=table2.F 
       OR table1.E=table2.F
```

Comment: This will work, but performance will be bad. I prefer the inner joins on 1 condition, with a UNION.

Comment: I'm not sure why performance would be worse than using `UNION`

Comment: Welcome!! Please accept the answer if you got your answer and Go Through this link you can understand the performace comparison of union VS join. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309936/use-a-union-or-a-join-what-is-faster

Comment: Could you please add additional info to this answer explaining why and how this bit of code fixes OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both join on table1's PK:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.A,
    T1.B
FROM
    table1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS T2 ON
        T1.A = T2.A AND
        T1.B = T2.B
WHERE
    T1.C = T2.F OR
    T1.D = T2.F OR
    T1.E = T2.F
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B
  FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.F IN (t1.C, t1.D, t1.E);
```